# Simple Injector gives lifestyle mismatch error while both classes are registered as singleton

Tags: inversion-of-control, simple-injector

So I have this Simple Injector IoC wire up code

```
container.RegisterSingleton<IMsgProcessor, PrometheusTickerPublisher>();
container.RegisterSingleton<ICollector, UpdatesPerSecondDataCollector>();
```

And when I try and run my app I am getting this error message

> A lifestyle mismatch is encountered. PrometheusTickerPublisher
>   (Singleton) depends on UpdatesPerSecondDataCollector (Transient).
>   Lifestyle mismatches can cause concurrency bugs in your application. 
>   Please see https://simpleinjector.org/dialm to understand this problem
>   and how to solve it.

I don't get this at all. Both items are registered as singletons. I then changed the registration to this, to see if I could be more explicit about it being a singleton

```
container.RegisterSingleton<IMsgProcessor, PrometheusTickerPublisher>();
container.AddRegistration(typeof(ICollector), CreateCollectorRegistration(container));

internal static Registration CreateCollectorRegistration(Container container)
{
    return
        Lifestyle.Singleton.CreateRegistration<ICollector>(
            () =>
            {
                var timeProvider = container.GetInstance<ITimeProvider>();
                return new UpdatesPerSecondDataCollector(timeProvider);
            }, container);
}
```

But this gives the same error

At this point I am completely lost, Any ideas

Comment: You only get this specific error in case you don't call `container.Verify()` at the end of the registration process. Verification is advised because it will give you much more information. For instance it would have signaled that `UpdatesPerSecondDataCollector` is a short circuited dependency, because `PrometheusTickerPublisher` depends on it instead of depending on `ICollector`.

Comment: Yeah we will add that everywhere now

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Calling `Container.Verify()` at the end of the registration process will check the container's [health](https://simpleinjector.org/diagnostics). If you do that, it would give you even more feedback:

> The configuration is invalid. The following diagnostic warnings were reported:
>
> -[Lifestyle Mismatch] PrometheusTickerPublisher (Singleton) depends on UpdatesPerSecondDataCollector (Transient).
>
> -[Short Circuited Dependency] PrometheusTickerPublisher might incorrectly depend on unregistered type UpdatesPerSecondDataCollector (Transient) instead of ICollector (Singleton).
>
> -[Ambiguous Lifestyles] The registration for UpdatesPerSecondDataCollector (Transient) maps to the same implementation (UpdatesPerSecondDataCollector) as the registration for ICollector (Singleton) does, but the registration maps to a different lifestyle. This will cause each registration to resolve to a different instance.
>
> -[Ambiguous Lifestyles] The registration for ICollector (Singleton) maps to the same implementation (UpdatesPerSecondDataCollector) as the registration for UpdatesPerSecondDataCollector (Transient) does, but the registration maps to a different lifestyle. This will cause each registration to resolve to a different instance.
>   See the Error property for detailed information about the warnings.
>
> Please see https://simpleinjector.org/diagnostics how to fix problems and how to suppress individual warnings.

The most interesting part here is the [Short Circuited Dependency warning](https://simpleinjector.org/diasc):

> **-[Short Circuited Dependency] `PrometheusTickerPublisher` might incorrectly depend on unregistered type `UpdatesPerSecondDataCollector` (Transient) instead of `ICollector` (Singleton).**

In other words, Simple Injector detects that you registered `UpdatesPerSecondDataCollector` through its `ICollector` as `Singleton`, but you are circumventing that `ICollector` registration by depending directly on the `UpdatesPerSecondDataCollector` implementation instead. This is called short-circuited, because instead of using the `ICollector` registration, you go directly to the (unregistered) implementation. This might cause all sorts of problems.

Because there is no explicit registration for `UpdatesPerSecondDataCollector`, Simple Injector will implicitly register it for you, and it uses the `Transient` lifestyle (unless you specify otherwise). The registration for `ICollector`, however, is a `Singleton`, so that will likely cause problems. This is again noted in the [Ambiguous Lifestyles warning](https://simpleinjector.org/diaal):

> -[Ambiguous Lifestyles] The registration for UpdatesPerSecondDataCollector (Transient) maps to the same implementation (UpdatesPerSecondDataCollector) as the registration for ICollector (Singleton) does, but the registration maps to a different lifestyle. This will cause each registration to resolve to a different instance.

Without calling `Verify`, all these issues stay undetected. The only verification Simple Injector does when resolving a type is the [Lifestyle Mismatch](https://simpleinjector.org/dialm), which is why you only got the following error:

> A lifestyle mismatch is encountered. PrometheusTickerPublisher (Singleton) depends on UpdatesPerSecondDataCollector (Transient).

Long story short, you didn't register `UpdatesPerSecondDataCollector` by itself, but only by its `ICollector` abstraction, causing Simple injector to implicitly make a `Transient` registration for `UpdatesPerSecondDataCollector` on your behalf. Because this registration is `Transient`, Simple Injector blocked the injection of it into the `Singleton` class `PrometheusTickerPublisher`. If you would have called `Container.Verify()`, there would be a very detailed problem description of what is going wrong, which is much more than just a simple Lifestyle Mismatch.

Answer (score 0):

Ok so I found out what the issue was, my class was expecting the exact `UpdatesPerSecondDataCollector` type rather than an `ICollector`, so I guess since I was not registering the type explicitly it was being resolved as transient each time by SimpleInjector. Solution was just to do this in IOC registration instead

```
container.RegisterSingleton<UpdatesPerSecondDataCollector>();
```

That is what my downstream class was expecting

Case closed